# in Psionic Item Creation how does power augmentation work?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, psionics

If i wanted to make a Psionic item that once per day allowed me to manifest Fate Link (http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/fateLink.htm) at an 7th Manifester Level, which means normally it could be augmented once, Would it manifest from the item with this augmentation? and What about other powers that have more than one augmentation option?

Answer (score 4):

The [rules](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/items/basics.htm#usingItems) are obnoxiously vague:

> Powers stored in command thought items are usually not augmented, because the manifester level of such an item is assumed to be the minimum possible to manifest the stored power.

> Powers stored in use-activated items are usually not augmented, because the manifester level of such an item is assumed to be the minimum possible to manifest the stored power.

It’s great to know that they’re usually minimum manifester level, but there’s zero information about what happens in the unusual cases where it’s not. Individual items must therefore specify, apparently.

Power stones actually do explicitly state that they can be augmented:

> Powers stored in power completion items are usually not augmented, because the manifester level of such an item is assumed to be the minimum necessary to manifest the stored power. However, an item’s description may specify otherwise (some power stones have manifester levels higher than the minimum required to manifest the stored power, and **are then assumed to be augmented as well**).

While power trigger items (dorjes, mostly, since psicrowns have special rules, including their own power points that can be used to augment) have the truly bizarre rule that they are augmented *if they deal HP damage.*

> Powers stored in power trigger items are not augmented. Such powers are assumed to be stored in the item at the minimum manifester level necessary to manifest the power. However, certain items may specify a higher manifester level than necessary. If such an item holds a power that deals hit point damage, the power is **assumed to be augmented to the maximum allowed by the power and the manifester level**.

In my opinion, it’s insane to not give users the benefit of the manifester level they’ve paid for by not having the item be augmented.

Comment: is it me or do you always seem to come up with the longest most well thought out answers. Its a shame there isnt more concrete ruleset

Comment: The next question is "Do you choose augments when using an item power, or when the item is made?"

Comment: Very good question. It gets even weirder when we get to powers with possible changes to manifestation time